how do i fix this: "depends: libicu74 (= 74.2-1ubuntu3.1) but 74.2-1ubuntu4 is to be installed" libgtk3-dev requires an older version as a dependent
i've been having a horrible time on windows seven so i decided to try linux mint and i'm having all sorts of issues getting stuff to work.  i'm on a fourteen year old laptop with no gpu.  would i have a better shot at getting allegro5 to work if i switched to a ubuntu?  seems like it probably has more support.
this is the problem i'm currently facing on mint?  just to get unicode to work for a library needed to use an allegro5 addon i would have to downgrade my a unicode package.
i don't think it's a good idea to downgrade libicu to an older version cause i feel like it's going to cause more problems then it's worth.  i just can't understand why libgtk-3-dev would need an older version in the first place.  since libicu is just unicode stuff I feel like there should be a way to get it to work with the newer version or there's some kind of bug but every time i try to fix anything i can never get it to work.
i'm wondering if i'd have an easier time if i switched to ubuntu.  it would be nice if things worked.  i remember my computer could run everything and do anything 14 years ago, but now just nothing works hardly.
which linux version is the best for someone like me who's trying to make a game engine for a pixel game?  i feel like linux mint is close to being good, but not quite there yet, and likely never will be any good because people just keep making new, more complicated, buggy, harder to run software that operating system creators can never keep up with.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)

When you take your question to a site that accepts Linux Mint questions, don't forget to provide release details; as deb packages are built for a specific release; and whilst CLI enquiries on packages can show all releases - if your release is known, more specific help can be provided. You're off-topic here due to your OS choice (your system isn't a Ubuntu system, only Ubuntu based)  FYI:  A quick look and your question is also release specific with mix of oracular and noble packages in your message.... so once you work out your release, check your sources!

FYI:  This isn't a forum but a more limited Question and Answer site; questions asking for opinions (such as which is best) are best dealt with on Forums (UbuntuForums for example; they use Ubuntu Discourse - but Linux Mint is off-topic on UD too) rather than a Q&A site like this. Your question should be a clearly defined single problem that can be solved in answers (many solutions/answers is fine) but key is a single answerable problem that isn't asking for opinion.  Refer on-topic (already provided) and https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask where you last paragraph is best on forum.
